# Is there a page maintained on Jose4J vulnerabilities if any posted on bitbucket?

Tags: jose4j

I am looking for a vulnerabilities list for JOSE4J if any. We want to apply the library in our product to validate Azure AD tokens and generate so called entitlement tokens which contain more product related data, we like the library a lot, but the question from the security team came up if there are any vulnerabilities identified for JOSE4J and if any where are they posted, and how bug fixes are communicated in case of a discovered vulnerability

Thanks

Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Release Notes](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Release%20Notes) of the project lists the changes made including anything security related.

Comment: Great, thanks Brian! You have one new customer! Love the customer support. Keep up the good work! :)